# MetaMask rewriting web pages?

Tags: metamask

I am working on a web application backend (completely unrelated to Ethereum) that returns XML in response to certain queries. I have just set up the environment again and came across something weird: displayed in the first tag in the root tag was a `<script>`, which clearly has no business being there. It looks like this:

```
<script>
/*global Web3*/ cleanContextForImports() require('web3/dist/web3.min.js') const LocalMessageDuplexStream = require('post-message-stream') 
[... too long ...]
</script>
```

I thought the code was broken, but on inspection it was MetaMask javascript code. I have MetaMask installed and running, but this is strange. Does MetaMask rewrite all pages like this? And why would it rewrite XML files, does it not detect HTML? The Content-Type is text/xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MetaMask does [both doctype and suffix checking](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/blob/master/app/scripts/contentscript.js#L67-L91) to only inject in html documents, and not inject in PDFs or XML.

It looks like you've found an edge case that still gets injected in.

You should [open a new issue with MetaMask](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/new) and give as many specific details about your situation as possible, especially if you can provide the xml document in question.

Comment: Done. I have probably played too much with such a banal issue, but what do you do. https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/1398